# Admin application not starting up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I have below spring boot  dependency :

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

and admin dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

At startup Application is failing with below error :

```
An attempt was made to call the method reactor.retry.Retry.retryMax(J)Lreactor/retry/Retry; but it does not exist. Its class, reactor.retry.Retry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/313158/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/addons/reactor-extra/3.1.7.RELEASE/reactor-extra-3.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/reactor/retry/Retry.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/313158/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/addons/reactor-extra/3.1.7.RELEASE/reactor-extra-3.1.7.RELEASE.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of reactor.retry.Retry

Note :After Updating version of spring and admin to 2.1.4 ,getting different errors

Are there any other dependencies required to start admin application

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot Admin uses Spring Boot version 2.1.4.RELEASE

Update your parent to this version

Comment: After updating getting below errors :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.AdminServerWebConfiguration.instancesController
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.AdminServerWebConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule